# jmeter Load Test Serevr down issues

Tags: testing, server, jmeter, load

I was used a load of ***100*** using ultimate thread group for execution in **NON GUI** Mode .
The Execution takes place around **5 mins**. only . After that my test environment got shut down. I am not able to drill down the issues. What could be the reason for server downs. my environment supports for **500** users.

Answer (score 0):

1. How do you know your environment supports 500 users?
2. 100 threads don't necessarily map to 100 real users, you need to consider a lot of stuff while designing your test, in particular:

   - Real users don't hammer the server non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations. So make sure you add [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) between requests and configure them to represent reasonable think times.
   - Real users use real browsers, real browsers download embedded resources (images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc) but they do it **only once**, on subsequent requests the resources are being returned from cache and no actual request is being made. Make sure to add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan
3. You need to add the load **gradually**, this way you will be able to state what was amount of threads (virtual users) where response time start exceeding acceptable values or errors start occurring. Generate a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), look into metrics and correlate them with the increasing load.
4. Make sure that your application under test has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Disk space, etc. You can monitor these counters using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test).
5. Check your application logs, most probably they will have some clue to the root cause of the failure. If you're familiar with the programming language your application is written in - using a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) during the load test can tell you the full story regarding what's going on, what are the most resources consuming functions and objects, etc.

Comment: Hello...Dmitri , our environment team told that we can send 500 concurrent sessions at a time it should handle until that.

Comment: we are new to jmeter tool for our application and we are thinking that jmeter is creating this problem for our environment. is it? if not what would we suggest to environment team? pls let me know . thanks in advance

Comment: And one more thing that when we ran the same test with the same specifications on "Locust" tool we didn't face these type of issues but when we ran in jmeter only we observed this issues. if possible can u explain why this could placed?